# Can't see Https traffic in fiddler - it only shows "tunnel" - https decryption enabled

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

1. I have a ASP.NET MVC based web site which runs on http.
2. From the above web site I'm making a https call to a web API
3. Configured fiddler as a proxy and trying to monitor the traffic using Fiddler Web Debugger (ver 4.4.8.4)

I only see "tunnel to" requests to the https web api sent from the MVC web application. Why am I not able to see other https traffic including request/response headers/body?

I have enabled decrypting https setting in fiddler. I have followed this link:
http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/help/faq.asp

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: As an alternative can I suggest that you also use IExplorer developer tools? just press F12 and select the http traffic section. I hope this helps

Comment: the call is being made from ASP.NET code on the server...

Comment: F12 developer tools work same as fiddler. you can see http traffic and the resources that are being loaded, even how long resources take to load.

Answer (score -2):

Let's step back a bit:

1. Is the HTTPS request to the *web API* being made from JavaScript on the client, or from ASP.NET code on the server?
2. Did the request actually succeed?
3. What, if anything, do you see in Fiddler's LOG tab?

Comment: Thanks for the response... it is from ASP.NET code on the server. The call succeeded as I can view the results retrieved. I'll check Fiddler's log and get back to you...

Comment: So, just to be clear here, you're running Fiddler *on the server*, right? Did you configure the the SERVER to trust the FiddlerRoot certificate at the MACHINE level using mmc.exe?